# Compare row by row among two column ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, sumifs

I have two columns of data, one with dollar amounts and another with a text value. I'm trying to create a formula at the bottom that will add together only the values in A for which the corresponding row in column B equals "Yes". So in the example below my formula would return a sum of 1000:

```
|    A     |    B     |
|500       |Yes       |
|150       |No        |
|500       |Yes       |
|533       |No        |

|1000      |
```

My actual spreadsheet has many more rows, so I want a formula that can compare the entire range in column A against the entire range in column B, row by row. Is this possible to do without having to set up a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B4,"Yes",A1:A4)
```

Adjust the ranges to suit but ensure they are of equal size.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! The applied formula works perfectly. How did I not find this sooner? Thank you!